# Flutter: Adding inkwell to my gridlist in order to use ontap () is throwing errors

Tags: flutter, ontap

Code is fine until I try and add inkwell()

'''
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: const Text("App Dev and QA process"),
centerTitle: true,
systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark),
body: AnimationLimiter(

```
    child: GridView.count(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
          parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(_w / 60),
      crossAxisCount: columnCount,

      children: List.generate(
        8,
        (int index) {
```

InkWell(
return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
position: index,
duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
columnCount: columnCount,
child: ScaleAnimation(
duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 900),
curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
child: FadeInAnimation(

```
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: _w / 30, left: _w / 60, right: _w / 60),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    borderRadius:
                        const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                        blurRadius: 40,
                        spreadRadius: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),


                  child:  Center(

                    child:  Text(appTodoList[index], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: GoogleFonts.laila(
                      textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),),

                  ),

                ),



              ),

            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('1 was clicked');
          }
          },
          );
        },

      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

'''

I'm trying to add onTap() so each grid block takes me to another page.

**Errors are:**

1. The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
2. Unexpected text 'return'.
3. Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.

Comment: you need to move the InkWell function call outside of the List.generate method and include the GestureDetector inside the child parameter of the InkWell method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `return` outside of `Inkwell` and add child to it.

```dart
List.generate(
  8,
      (int index) {
    return InkWell(
      child: AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(),
      onTap: () {},
    );
  }
)
```